# How do I flag/report/complain about a message I got on Stack Overflow Jobs?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I received a message on Stack Overflow Jobs which violates [the rules](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/house-rules) (and is rather inept, too).

**How do I report the violation?**

I don't see any “flag” or “report” option on the message page or the company's page. A comment suggested I should email careers@stackoverflow.com based on [this page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/support), but I also see text implying that that is support for employers only, and it is not linked anywhere obvious starting from the messages page.

Comment: perhaps: careers@stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Dagon Perhaps, yes. But since I couldn't find a clear answer, I thought the question was worth asking publicly and generically.

Comment: the support link (http://careers.stackoverflow.com/support) on the bottom of the jobs section seems clear enough to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's fine to contact careers@stackoverflow.com for this. The team that picks up those messages will get in contact with the employer and make sure it doesn't happen again.

You can also block the employer and they will not be able to contact you or see you in candidate search anymore.