# Failing to contact Jobs support

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

As per [my previous question on the subject](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331587/how-do-i-flag-report-complain-about-a-message-i-got-on-stack-overflow-jobs), I want to report a problematic employer on Stack Overflow Jobs. I got the advice to send an email to careers@stackoverflow.com.

I did so on August 5, from kpreid@switchb.org. 20 minutes later, I got a response which was *exactly the text of my message, not quoted*, followed by the Stack Overflow logo. I responded asking for clarification and have heard nothing since.

If you, by which I mean a relevant Stack Exchange employee, could look into what went wrong here it would be appreciated.

Comment: You might not be able to get emails from Jobs, but sharing your email address like this will certainly make you feel less lonely.

Comment: @Knu and Cody Gray — My email address is on my web site. Please do not obfuscate things just for the sake of my inbox.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So sorry about that! I found your ticket and have no idea why it didn't send a response.

We sent an email to the their sales rep on 8/9:

> Your cusotmer is sending terrible messages. See the
>   email below from a user; they're violating several rules. If they
>   don't clean up their messages, we'll have to revoke their access.

We'll continue to monitor their messages. It usually takes a week or two to get everything straightened out.

Comment: Hopefully you didn't misspell customer.

Comment: And if you did, the canonical misspelling is costumer.

Comment: "cannonical mispelling", made me smile :-)